# Работа с Donation Alerts API и NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, requests

На сайте donation alerts нет подробной документации. Пытался сам сделать, в итоге я всё равно не понимаю как авторизоватся через api. Единственное что выдает - это `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}`

Пример кода:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('https://www.donationalerts.com/api/v1/alerts/donations', {
    params: {
        'Authorization Bearer': 'tokenSample123456789'
    }
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.url);
    console.log(response.data.explanation);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Делал реквесты с помощью axios потому, что в других случаях выдавал undefined. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с их api

Answer (score 2):

Так ты не правильно отправляешь хидер, нужно `Bearer` в значение писать, а не в ключ.

```
params: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer tokenSample123456789'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде все подробно описано: https://www.donationalerts.com/apidoc#authorization__scopes

Совершенно стандартная авторизация, ничем не отличается от других OAuth.

Comment: Так мне в любом случае выдается  `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}`, и при в ведённых данных и пустой.

Answer (score 1):

При "запросе авторизации" пользователь должен **УЖЕ** быть авторизован в donationalerts.

https://www.donationalerts.com/apidoc

> When the user clicks the link, **they must first log in to the service**, to authenticate their identity (unless they are already logged in). Then they will be prompted by the service to authorize or deny the application access to their account. Here is an example authorize application prompt.

Вот такая глупость от DA. Нигде подобного не встречал